# Determining what version of Flask is installed

Tags: python, flask

What's the easiest way to determine which version of [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) is installed?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

As of flask 0.7 (June 28th, 2011), a `__version__` attribute can be found on the flask module.

```
>> import flask
>> flask.__version__
```

Keep in mind that because prior to flask 0.7 there was no `__version__` attribute, the preceding code will result in an attribute error on those older versions.

For versions older than flask 0.7, you might be able to determine it using pkg_resources as shown below:

```
>>> import pkg_resources
>>> pkg_resources.get_distribution('flask').version
'0.6.1'
```

This won't work 100% though. It depends on the user having the pkg_resources library installed (it might come by default with a Linux distribution's python installation, but since it's not part of the standard library you can't be positive), and also that the user installed flask in a way that pkg_resources can find it (for example, just copying the full flask source code into your directory puts it out of the range of pkg_resources).

Answer (score 23):

More general way of doing it is :

```
pip freeze
```

It will list all installed python packages and their versions.
If you want to see just flask then try :

```
pip freeze | grep flask
```

Answer (score 21):

Via the python interpreter.

```
>> import flask
>> flask.__version__
'0.7.2'
```

If flask was installed via pip or easy_install, you can always use the 'pip freeze' command.

Comment: While that may work with newer versions of Flask, I just confirmed that `flask.__version__` does not work with Flask 0.6.1.

Comment: I upgraded Flask to 0.7.2 and confirmed that `flask.__version__` does work. Time marches on.

Answer (score 13):

**It's quite simple !**

*In your terminal:*

```
pip freeze | grep Flask
```

*The output should be something like this:*

```
Output: Flask==0.12
```

Answer (score 9):

Tested whith Flask 1.0.2

Inside the venv run
`flask --version`

Answer (score 8):

If someone is trying to determine flask version via **Anaconda Command Prompt** then just run the following command:

```
flask --version
```

Above command will give following output format:

```
Python 3.7.3
Flask 1.1.1
Werkzeug 0.15.4
```

Answer (score 3):

using dpkg:

```
dpkg -l | grep flask
```

output:

```
ii  python-flask 0.8-1 all micro web framework based on Werkzeug, Jinja2 and good intentions
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import flask
>>> flask.__version__        #(To find the version)
'1.0.2'
>>> print flask.__file__     #(To find out the path where it is installed)
/usr/local/rnt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/__init__.pyc
```

Answer (score 2):

If managing with pip can just use list command to see all the packages and versions

`pip list`

Answer (score 2):

**Update on Flask version 1.1.2**

1. If Flask not installed then go to the required conda environment and write:

```
$ conda activate "name of conda environment" //py3 in my case
(py3)$ conda install flask
```

2. Post installation check the version with command:

```
(py3)$ flask --version
```

**Please Note**: `__version__` is not an attribute of flask anymore for the latest versions and thus `flask.__version__` would throw an error

**Terminal Output**

```
(py3) xxxxxx@xxxxx:~$ flask --version
Python 3.7.7
Flask 1.1.2
Werkzeug 1.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

just type **pip show flask** on cmd.
You will get all the information about the installed flask.
it will show you :
name
location
version and many more

Comment: Doesn't this just show Pypi information? Not the current installed version? Or even if it is installed?

Comment: then you write from flask import Flask in your IDE (pyCharm). If it does not show any red line or error this means it is installed Else it will show an error or red line whenever you import flask. You can also try this : python -m flask --version

Answer (score 0):

**Flask 3.0.0**(released on *2023-09-30*) deprecated the `__version__` attribute and will be removed in **Flask 3.1**. The recommended way to access the version would be by using [`importlib.metadata.version` API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html#distribution-versions).

```
>>> import flask
>>> import importlib
>>> flask.__version__
<stdin>:1: DeprecationWarning: The '__version__' attribute is deprecated and will be removed in Flask 3.1. Use feature detection or 'importlib.metadata.version("flask")' instead.
'3.0.0'
>>> 
>>> importlib.metadata.version("flask")
'3.0.0'
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just type:

```
python -m flask --version
```

Output:

```
Python 3.7.2 
Flask 1.1.1 
Werkzeug 0.16.0
```

Answer (score -1):

Type `flask --version` in your interpreter, for example: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzGDB.png)

Comment: How is this answer different from the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53171941/840340 ?

Answer (score -2):

```
pip show fastapi uvicorn
```

Output :

```
Name: fastapi
Version: 0.75.0
Summary: FastAPI framework, high performance, easy to learn, fast to code, ready for production
Home-page: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi
Author: Sebastián Ramírez
Author-email: tiangolo@gmail.com
License: None
Location: /home/mind/Desktop/FASTAPIBasic-/fastenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: starlette, pydantic
Required-by: 
---
Name: uvicorn
Version: 0.17.6
Summary: The lightning-fast ASGI server.
Home-page: https://www.uvicorn.org/
Author: Tom Christie
Author-email: tom@tomchristie.com
License: BSD
Location: /home/mind/Desktop/FASTAPIBasic-/fastenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: h11, click, asgiref
Required-by:
```

Comment: Question asked about Flask